# User gone from stats.SE

Tags: discussion, status-completed, deleted-accounts

I've noticed that user @svadali has disappeared from the [all reputation page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all). He had about 6000 reputation, but was inactive for quite a long time. It is possible to find references if you search for svadali in stackexchange.com, where his id is now substituted with user28 (28 was his user id). I would like to know what happened. Did he specifically ask to be removed, or this was some automatic clean-up procedure?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

He asked to be removed; it just happens sometimes.

<s>Anyway, there is no automatic cleaning system, so inactive users should not be worried ;-)</s>

Comment: any reasons why he did that? Just curious :)

Comment: @mpiktas I know nothing about it -- he directly asked the SE team.

Comment: @mp Actually, the SE team *hinted* that he asked.  They're cagey about such things.  As well they should be: although we all have probably felt the loss of Srikant's attention, this is a private matter between an individual and the site.  We still don't really know whether there is an automatic cleaning procedure for dead accounts!

Comment: @whu see http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/02/when-is-an-account-abandoned/

Comment: @Jeff Thanks for pointing out that blog post: it clearly describes how you clean up dormant accounts.